# How to play dynamically loaded audio files by clicking respective divs?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide dynamically loaded audio elements, and instead have the div they rest inside play the mp3 file when clicked. I tried to make a function play() by using var audio=document.getElementsbyTagName and use "audio" tag, but it didn't work, and the getElementById only played the first audio on both divs. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en-US">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>load files</TITLE>  
<SCRIPT>
function get_list_of_files_from_html( html_string ){
    var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
    el.innerHTML = html_string;

    var list_of_files = el.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

    var return_string ='<UL>';

    for(var i=5; i < list_of_files.length ; i++){
        var current_string = list_of_files[i];
        var new_string =
            current_string.toString().replace(
                /http:\/\/www.website.com/~user\/programmingfinal\//g,''
            );
        return_string += '<li><div class="floating">'+new_string +
                         '<audio controls> <source src = "' +
                         current_string + '" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
        return_string += '</div>';
    }
    return_string += '</UL>';
    return return_string;
}

function loadDoc(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =
                get_list_of_files_from_html( this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET",
        "http://www.website.com/~user/programmingfinal/audiofiles/",
        true);
        xhttp.send();
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body onload="loadDoc()">
<div id="container"  class="container">
</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

How would i use an onclick function to play the respective string mp3 files in the div? I was trying to do something like this but it's not working:

```
    for(var i=5; i < list_of_files.length ; i++){
        var current_string = list_of_files[i];
        var new_string =
            current_string.toString().replace(
                /http:\/\/www.website.com\/~user\/programmingfinal\//g,''
            );
        return_string += '<li><div class="floating" onclick="play(/"' +
                        current_string + '/")">' + new_string +
                        '<audio> <source src = "' + current_string +
                        '" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
        return_string += '</div>';
    }
    return_string += '</UL>';
    return return_string;            
}

function play(){
    new_string.play(file);
}
```

For this particular attempt, it is saying "invalid regular expression:missing /. However, none of my various attempts have worked.

Comment: getElementsByClassName ( dont forget the s )

Comment: but there is no class name for audio files is there?

Comment: Make one yourself and make a group out of them and you can set effects if one is playing get the one its id and blur all the others with the same class

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're loading your audio elements via `XMLHttpRequest`, this is probably an issue of the fact that your elements aren't available on page load. As such, your selector `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')` cannot target them.

What I would recommend is turning your request to load your audio files into a function, and then chaining a **[promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** to the response:

```
function loadDoc(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = resolve;
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Now you can invoke it with:

```
request('GET', 'http://www.website.com/~user/programmingfinal/audiofiles/')
.then(function (e) {
    var audio = document.getElementsbyTagName('audio');
    // Process audio files here
}, function (e) {
    // Handle errors
});
```

Processing the **[`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)** after the load. Now you should have access to the relevant elements in your `.then()`, though note that anything you want to do controlling the audio must be done inside the same `.then()`!

Hope this helps! :)